# React Raising an event from child component to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

I am fairly new to both JS and react and was trying to learn it via a Youtube tutorial that was from 4 years ago, so there may be some changes to the code that I am unaware of. I have looked at other similar posts on a similar issue and I have not found a solution to my problem in them.

We were writing a shopping cart app and we had a Counters class that holds multiple objects from the Counter class. For each counter component we had a span element and two button elements, one to increment the number in the span element and one to delete the component itself. We just started implementing the delete button and tried to log to the console to see if the button was responsive. This is where I ran into some issues. When I checked the component in my react developer tools extension I got that the onDelete event is undefined, and when I clicked the button nothing happened. I have specified a function to handle the event in the parent component.

Here are my code:

[image: Counter Class]
[image: Counters Class]

How should I write the code to properly raise an event by the Child component and for the parent component to listen and respond accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a typo in your `Counters` component, you write

`onDelete={this.handlDelete}`

where it should be

`onDelete={this.handleDelete}`

and as a tip, the current "go to" way of doing react is by using react function component with hooks, not classes anymore, so you may want to change your code.

and another thing, this kind of typo bug won't happen if you are using typescript, so I also suggest you to try to learn it

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I can't believe it was such a simple mistake. I have been trying to look at other tutorials for cross referencing for a while now and I couldn't find the issue.